# Scala: Canonical way to write to file / jar in Scala 2.11

Tags: scala, jar, io

I have the following method (in effect a function)

```
def addToJar(jarOut: JarOutputStream, file: File, reldir: String): Unit =
{
  val fName = reldir + file.getName         
  val fNameMod = if (file.isDirectory) fName + "/" else fName
  val entry = new JarEntry(fNameMod)
  entry.setTime(file.lastModified)         
  jarOut.putNextEntry(entry)
  if (file.isDirectory)
  {
     jarOut.closeEntry
     file.listFiles.foreach(i => addToJar(jarOut, i, fName + "/"))
  }
  else
  {         
     var buf = new Array[Byte](1024)
     val in = new FileInputStream(file)
     Stream.continually(in.read(buf)).takeWhile(_ != -1).foreach(jarOut.write(buf, 0, _))
     in.close
     jarOut.closeEntry()
  }         
}
```

I've written this after looking at other questions and blog posts, but the following questions remain:

Should there be try-catch blocks?

Is it possible to use a Scala.io class in place of java.io.fileinputstream?

Is it correct that the buffer write method is faster than using java.nio.channels.FileChannel, Apache Commons IO FileUtils.copyFile or Java 7's Files.copy?

For a big project is there significant performance to be gained from writing the whole jar creation utility in C++ and just calling out to it once?

**Note:** at the time of writing the last development milestone for Scala 2.11,M6 has not been released. however my understanding is that there will be no additions to Scala.io in it.